# Angular - How to configure environment specific CDN URLs in styles.scss

Tags: angular

Below is my `styles.scss` file

```
@import url('https://ocd.myurl.com/cdn/guide/fonts/Lato/latofonts.css');  // for DEV env
```

Similarly I have same URLs for all my environments like

```
@import url('https://ocq.myurl.com/cdn/guide/fonts/Lato/latofonts.css');  // for QA env
@import url('https://ocu.myurl.com/cdn/guide/fonts/Lato/latofonts.css');  // for UAT env
@import url('https://ocp.myurl.com/cdn/guide/fonts/Lato/latofonts.css');  // for PROD env
```

If they are something related to JS, I can use `config.dev.json` etc. for all environments and pull from those config files to my components. But how can we do this environment specific imports into `styles.scss` file? Please suggest.

Comment: You can add a `styles` array to your build configs in angular.json where you can change which .scss files are imported. You could have imports.dev.scss, imports.staging.scss etc, and styles.scss would only have style data without imports.

Comment: Can you please provide any example or reference link on the implementation?

Comment: You can check the Angular documentation at [Additional build and test options](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#additional-build-and-test-options). In the `angular.json` file, you can find a `build`, `serve`, and `test` block where you can configure the behavior for development or production.